# Meteor - How to handle external API connection errors?

Tags: node.js, api, meteor

I'm using a few external API's (some in timers, every minute or so) and sometimes I get some connection errors because of network problems or because the external systems are down for some reason. When I get this errors, the app restarts, and if the error persists the app continues restarting.

[image]

Any ideas on how can I ignore the connection error and keep the app running?

Code Example:

```
  try {
      var req = https.request(options, callback);
      req.write(JSON.stringify(params));
      req.end();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
```

Comment: Need to see more code related this.  But generally speaking, it's because you're not handling those errors.

Comment: Why not just a [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block?

Comment: @dzm Updated the question with a code example

Comment: @MichelFloyd Updated the question with a code example

Comment: @MMrj You don't want to `throw e` in your try/catch.  Instead, just log it.  You're catching an error and then throwing an error, which will cause your node server to stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code example.  You're doing `throw e` inside your try catch.  Essentially, you're catching an error and then throwing the error.  Just do `console.error(err)` or however you want to handle that error, without throwing.  This is what will cause your instance to stop.